# How to move/copy folders using wildcards in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am having trouble with a simple "move" command in a batch file.

To give some potentially helpful context, the overarching purpose of the file I am writing is to sort named folders into alphabetically labeled folders.

For example, a folder called "Allen, Jake" would be sorted into a folder called "A" and a folder called "Brown, Sarah" would be sorted into a folder called "B" and so on.

Here is the line of code I am having trouble with:

```
    move "%SourceDirectory%\A*" "%DestinationDirectory%\A"
```

When I run the command I expect a folder called "Allen, Jake" to be moved from %SourceDirectory% into "%DestinationDirectory\A".

Instead, I see the following output:

```
    C:\Users\alecm\Desktop>move "C:\Users\alecm\Desktop\Source\A*" 
    "C:\Users\alecm\Desktop\Destination\A"

    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I presume I'm making a simple syntax error here but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance for taking the time to look over this.

Answer (score 1):

The `move` command does not accept wildcards. Change the `SOURCE_BASE` and `TARGET_BASE` directories to yours.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "SOURCE_BASE=C:\src\t"
SET "TARGET_BASE=C:\src\t\new"

FOR %%L IN (A) DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A:D "%SOURCE_BASE%\%%L*"') DO (
        SET "DNAME=%%~F"
        SET "FIRST_LETTER=!DNAME:~0,1!"
        SET "NEW_DIR=%TARGET_BASE%\!FIRST_LETTER!"

        IF NOT EXIST "!NEW_DIR!" (MKDIR "!NEW_DIR!")
        MOVE "%%~dpnxF" "!NEW_DIR!"
    )
)
```

If this is placed into a .bat script, be sure to double the percent `%` characters for the F variable. `%%F`

If you want to do more than just `A*` directories, change the first FOR loop to `FOR %%d IN (A B C D) DO (`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am trying to move folders specifically, so I tried this command with and without the dash in the switch "/A:-D". In both instances, no folders were successfully moved. Am I possibly misinterpreting or misusing some aspect of your code? Here is the output I am receiving when I run the command followed by a pause:

C:\Users\alecm\Desktop>(
MOVE "Alan, Jacob" "C:\Users\alecm\Desktop\Destination\A"
 Pause
)
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @AlecMusheno - I misunderstood. The `/A:-D` means `not directories`. I will change the answer to `/A:D`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the command still does not move files. In the output I pasted above I had already removed the "-" from "/A:-D". Is there anything else you can think of that I should try? Thanks again for writing back.

Comment: Try using `echo` before the `MOVE` command to see what the command will look like. Does the directory "C:\Users\alecm\Desktop\Destination\A" already exist?